# Applescript copy name of selected image in preview

Tags: applescript, preview

I have several images opened in one Preview window. I'm trying to copy the file name of the selected image in the window.

Currently, I'm using

```
tell application "Preview" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
```

This does not work, probably because it copies the file and its path (I only need the file name as string)

thanks a lot

Comment: What version of OS X/macOS?

Comment: for OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is along the lines of what you are looking for?

```
tell application "Preview"
    set thePath to path of document of front window as POSIX file as alias
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    set theName to name of (get properties of thePath)
end tell
set the clipboard to theName
```

Comment: It should copy file name of  the selected image in the tumbnails

Comment: @DomiNic  Unless I am completely misunderstanding… That's exactly what it does

Comment: If the goal is to place the name of the file on the Clipboard, then `set theName to name of document of front window` really isn't at all necessary and should be deleted. In the next line, simply change `theName` to `of front window` so it's `set thePath to path of document of front window as POSIX file as alias`. After all, why have to type more _code_ then is needed to get to the end goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
    set the text item delimiters to "/"

    get the path of the front document in application "Preview"
        --> "/Users/CK/Pictures/Screenshots/Screen Shot 2018-03-29 at 16.06.jpg"
    get the last text item of the result
        --> "Screen Shot 2018-03-29 at 16.06.jpg"


    --OR--


    get the path of the front document in application "Preview"
    tell application "System Events" to get the name of the file result
        --> "Screen Shot 2018-03-29 at 16.06.jpg"


    --THEN--


    set the clipboard to the result
```

Comment: Just curious why you chose the route you did, because Preview.app’s scripting dictionary has a “name property” (get and set) for both window and document classes

Comment: @wch1zpink I did it this way because I interpreted the OP as wanting to obtain the filename, which, in my first thought, included the file extension.  He doesn’t state this one way or another and I don’t know if "filename" is formally defined in this sense, but as your script returns just the name without the extension, I felt it would make sense to offer the OP a means to get the extension as well.  I imagine he might just want the name as you’ve provided, but hopefully someone else will find this useful.

Comment: I just triple checked my script and In both the script editor and script debugger apps, the result does include the file extension
https://i.imgur.com/JVkvDpW.png

Comment: @wch1zpink [My results](https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/0e0i2p2i3S0E3U431x3G/Screen%20Shot%202018-03-30%20at%2000.34.jpg) appear to differ from your own.  I believe the reason for this is that the `name` property will return what is referred to in other places as the `displayed name`.  Therefore, if the file has its extension set to be hidden in *Finder*, the output of your script will reflect this.

Comment: You are, in fact, correct with your observation of.. if name extensions are hidden in Finder prefs, the code I posted originally would only return the displayed name.  I adjusted my code to account for that.  Great catch by the way